# Can´t install chatterbot library

Tags: python, chatterbot

I try to install with command `pip install chatterbot` with the CMD.

In the path C./ it seems to be installed python 2.7 in a directory called python27 but there is another python dir in `c:\users\arcanet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\`. When I try to install throws me the following exception:

> Command
>   "c:\users\arcanet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
>   c:\users\arcanet\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip
>   install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
>   C:\Users\ARCANET\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_w62yget\overlay
>   --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel>0.32.0.<0.33.0 Cython
>   cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0 preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0 murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0
>   thinc==7.0.0.dev6" failed with error code 1 in Noneimport telegram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going into your **advanced system settings** then clicking **environment Variables** in the bottom right. Underneath the System Variables pane scroll down until you see **Path**, go ahead and click edit. You may already have a Python path added, if so delete it and click new. Open a file explorer to your python 2.7 scripts directory and copy the url from the top and paste that into the new file path.

Hope this helped!

- Maverick

Comment: Well i was looking for a python path, but wasn't there. I just created a new variable like you told but it keeps the same error.

Comment: Is the path you created along the lines of something like c:\users\arcanet\appdata\local\programs\python\(python version)\Scripts\?

Comment: Yes ¿does the name of the variable affects? i just named it "python".

Comment: Could you please supply me with the file url you put into the path?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see the variable path. It is solved, thanks.